# Is digital Ortophoto of Hungary publicly available?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uses-of-open-data

It's quick and easy question regarding available WMS services in Hungary. I'm searching available Ortophoto or topographic images for Hungary but without any luck.

I must say that I'm having difficulties navigating through Hungary GIS data as I'm not native Hungarian speaker but in my search I've stumbled upon Hungarian Geoportal and if I understood correctly one must pay for ortofoto and topographic images.

Are there any publicly available WMS services that includes orthophoto and/or topographic maps?

Comment: have a look at https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov and https://www.naturalearthdata.com

Comment: Also try geoseer: https://www.geoseer.net/s.php?q=orthophoto+east+europe. Keep in mind that the data you want may be included in a larger data set, so try replacing "Hungary" with "Europe" in your search.